# python matplotlib - retrieve xaxis_major_locator as time value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a timeserie with matplotlib (timeserie looks like the following):
[image]

Part of the code that i use sets major locator for each day at 0AM:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 3))
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax,quotes, width=0.01)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.DayLocator(interval=1) )
```

I would like to plot a darker background on the chart for each day between 16pm and 8am, and planning to use `axvspan` for that task. Considering that axvspan takes as argument `axvspan(xmin, xmax)` I was wondering if it would be possible to **retrieve the xaxis_major_locator as a x value** in order to pass it to axvspan as `axvspan(xmin=major_locator-3600s, xmax=major_locator+3600s)`

Edit: I found that function in the docs: http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Locator

If anyone knows how to returns a list of ticker location from the Xaxis_major with it let me know. Thanks.

Edit2: if i use `print(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator())` i receive as a return `<matplotlib.dates.DayLocator object at 0x7f70f3b34090>` How do i extarct a list of tick location from that?

Answer (score 0):

ok found it...
majors=ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()